# Merged Rows in Sencha

Tags: javascript, extjs

I am trying to figure out how to merge row cells like this in EXT JS. Can anyone provide an example?

```
Customer   | Product    | QTY | Model  | Price
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
           |            | 2   | 2      |  100
Acme       | Mixer      | 1   |17      |  200
           |            | 2   |33      |   50
====================================================
           |            | 1   | 2      |   10
Toro       | Mower      | 4   |14      |   20
           |            | 3   |31      |    5
====================================================
```

Comment: What have you tried so far, and what isn't working specifically? Show your work!

Comment: Check out the [grouping feature](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.0/#!/api/Ext.grid.feature.Grouping), not sure it's exactly what you want.

Comment: Grouping is a good fit, also rowexpander can give you more options to fill in more data into the rows.